# A particular page isn't showing any content

Tags: c#, asp.net

After I click my login button, it is supposed to redirect to "Edit.aspx". When it opens the page, it doesn't show anything but the content put in the master page.

Here's the code for EnterSite.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="Edit.aspx" OnAuthenticate="MyLogin_Authenticate">
</asp:Login>

</asp:Content>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
protected void MyLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string User = Login1.UserName;
    string Pass = Login1.Password;
    if (User == "Admin" && Pass == "Hello1234")
        e.Authenticated = true;
}
```

Here is the code for Edit.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Menu ID="ManageBlogPosts" runat="server" Text="Manage Blog Entries" NavigateUrl="ManageBlogPost.aspx"></asp:Menu>
    <asp:Menu ID="ManageStreetPhotos" runat="server" Text="Manage Street Photos" NavigateUrl="ManageStreetPhotos.aspx"></asp:Menu>
    <asp:Menu ID="ManagePeoplePhotos" runat="server" Text="Manage People Photos" NavigateUrl="ManagePeoplePhotos.aspx"></asp:Menu>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Try plain HTML content in edit.aspx to make sure it is displayed.

Comment: Okay, it shows... I added a link.

Comment: menus have not any item to show.

Comment: Isn't that what the "Text" property is for? Either way, I added some text between the tags and it gives me an error, saying there shouldn't be text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make **menu** use this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="ManageBlogPosts" runat="server" Text="Manage Blog Entries" NavigateUrl="ManageBlogPost.aspx">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/a.aspx" Text="a" Value="a"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/b.aspx" Text="b" Value="b"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/c.aspx" Text="c" Value="c"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Lol, I'd wager that's right... Dang it. I thought I saw it the way I did it earlier, as I was searching how to use it...

Comment: What is the Value property for?

Comment: it is optional to use

Comment: Well, it definitely is what I'm looking for. Thanks again Samiey!